# Zariski density of points over completion

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I have a simple question which I couldn't find a reference to.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective irreducible variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose we base change to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (the $p$-adics) and $X_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ contains a $\mathbb{Q}_p$ point. Does it follow that the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ points are Zariski dense in $X_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$?

(I think my hypothesis should be correct, but feel free to change it as you see fit)

Edit: I thought I should include my thoughts. My guess is that the answer is yes. The reason is suppose I have $f(x,y)\in\mathbb Q[x,y]$ and there is $x_0,y_0\in\mathbb Q_p$ such that $f(x_0,y_0)=0$. Then by Hensel's lemma I should be able to vary $y_0$ modulo $p^n$ for large enough $n$ and still be able to solve for $x$. This gives an analytic open neighborhood around the point. I think there is a general statement in the literature somewhere that covers this which I couldn't find it.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Q}_p$ point?

Comment: Point defined over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, i.e. a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\; \mathbb{Q}_p\hookrightarrow X_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$.

Comment: @user242231 How can a set of morphisms to $X_{\mathbf{Q}_p}$ be dense in $X_{\mathbf{Q}_p}$? Do you mean the set of images of $\mathbf{Q}_p$-points? In any case, it can happen that $X(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is empty for non-empty $X$, so the answer is no.

Comment: @tsa Yes, I mean the images. In the question I assumed that $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is nonempty. What can be said in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is true. It does not require the projective hypothesis.

$\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a *large field*, a notion introduced by Florian Pop in 1996 (see [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2118581)). More generally, any field that is complete with respect to a nontrivial absolute value is large (see example A2 on p. 2 [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pop/Research/files-Res/LF_4Sep2013.pdf)). Being large is precisely the property you are asking about.

Proposition 2.6 of that second link states:

> For a field $k$, the following assertions are equivalent: i) $k$ is a large field. ii) For each irreducible $k$-variety $X$ one has: $X_{reg}(k)=X_{sm}(k)$ is either empty or Zariski dense. iii) For each irreducible $k$-variety $X$ one has: If $X_{sm}(k)$ is non-empty then $X(k)$ is Zariski dense.

Here $X_{reg}(k)$ and $X_{sm}(k)$ denote the $k$-points of the regular and smooth loci respectively.